# crontab not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have referred 10+ links of similar issue but none of one worked. I am working in **ubuntu 16.04 docker container**. I am trying to set cron jobs. I referred this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps) to install cron.

for making demo add below line in `crontab -e` (as a root user)

```
* * * * * echo "Run this command every minute" >> /var/www/public/cronfile.log
```

when saving file it will notify `crontab: installing new crontab` but none of file created at a specified location.

Below steps are I am trying to sort out that issues but none of one worked.

1. change crontab `SHELL=/bin/sh` to `SHELL=/bin/bash`
2. append 2>&1 in crontab -e

   `* * * * * echo "Run this command every minute" >> /var/www/public/cronfile.log 2>&1`
3. check permission `/etc/crontab` (root user I am also run as a root user `crontab -e`)
4. I could not found any log file in /var/log/. also  var/log/syslog not found. kindly note it is a ubuntu docker container. I have tried with below command but I could not found any cron related logs.

   `find / -type f -name '*.log'`

**note:** Actually the origin of the issues come from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134561/cron-logs-not-generated-magento-2-0-8). If you need any additional info please mention in comment.

can anyone assist me what I am doing wrong here?

---

## Update

I tried the same replication of @BMitch answer but that will also  produce same problem. I am waiting more than five minutes but no cron log file generated in `/var/www/public/cronfile.log`, please see my stuff

```
[root@bu bu]# docker run -it --rm ubuntu
root@a256be07f23a:/# ( apt-get update && apt-get install cron ) >/install.log 2>&1
root@a256be07f23a:/# service cron start
 * Starting periodic command scheduler cron                                                              [ OK ] 
root@a256be07f23a:/# mkdir -p /var/www/public
root@a256be07f23a:/# crontab - <<EOF
> * * * * * echo "Run this command every minute" >> /var/www/public/cronfile.log
> EOF
root@a256be07f23a:/# crontab -l
* * * * * echo "Run this command every minute" >> /var/www/public/cronfile.log
root@a256be07f23a:/# date
Fri Sep  9 04:47:50 UTC 2016
root@a256be07f23a:/# date
Fri Sep  9 04:50:59 UTC 2016
root@a256be07f23a:/# ls -al /var/www/public
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  6 Sep  9 04:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 20 Sep  9 04:47 ..
root@a256be07f23a:/# date
Fri Sep  9 04:51:21 UTC 2016
root@a256be07f23a:/# ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
total 4
-rw------- 1 root crontab 254 Sep  9 04:47 root
root@a256be07f23a:/#
```

version check

```
root@660f8f6d128e:/# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with this question. please mention the reason for down vote otherwise the mistake is still remains.

Answer (score 2):

Docker is an application isolation tool, unlike how virtual machines are an OS isolation tool. That means you run your application inside of a Docker container, and in that container no other OS services components are running by default. So if you configure your crontab, you don't have the cron daemon running that would process that file and kick off the jobs. To have this run for you, a `cron -f` needs to be run to launch the daemon in the foreground. If your container runs another application (most likely), then you'd need a tool like supervisord to launch multiple applications to also run cron.

---

Edit: this is my attempt to reproduce your error in my lab after starting cron. As you can see, the file is created for me:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# ( apt-get update && apt-get install cron ) >/install.log 2>&1
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# service cron start
 * Starting periodic command scheduler 
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# mkdir -p /var/www/public
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# crontab - <<EOF
> * * * * * echo "Run this command every minute" >> /var/www/public/cronfile.log
> EOF
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# crontab -l
* * * * * echo "Run this command every minute" >> /var/www/public/cronfile.log
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# ls -al /var/www/public
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  7 11:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  7 11:53 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30 Sep  7 11:54 cronfile.log
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# date
Wed Sep  7 11:54:18 UTC 2016
root@f2e78e1bacde:/# ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
total 4
-rw------- 1 root crontab 255 Sep  7 11:53 root
root@f2e78e1bacde:/#
```

Comment: I am 100% sure cron already running. "docker exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash". this command take me to the ubuntu terminal here I can install cron then run "service cron start" when I check status it is running. after that only I tried above mentioned all. by the way I tried your solution too cron -f but it throws "Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session". here any point am I wrong? please mention in comment.

Comment: With cron running, I can't reproduce your problem. My root crontab gets created in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root as expected, and after creating the /var/www/public directory, the /var/www/public/cronfile.log is created with a datestamp that changes each minute. I'm also not seeing any errors when cron is stopped and I launch it with `cron -f`. Since you didn't mention that you're starting cron in your question, perhaps there's something else not mentioned that's breaking this for you.

Comment: thanks for your effort! I had done what you update, please see my updated question. I did the same more than 30+ time from yesterday :-) cron have any error log (like apache error log in /var/log/httpd/error.log)

Comment: I noticed you didn't start your update from a clean container with your `docker run` command. Please include everything needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: please see my updated question, I did exactly what you did. also I have tried in my running container too but the problem still remains. please review https://codeshare.io/T82Nd

Comment: codeshare.io seems to be down right now. Did you wait for 60 seconds to give the cron job time to run? Your cron configuration was updated at 5:02 and the directory listing was taken before 5:03.

Comment: please see my updated question. it clearly show the wait time. may be it is a bug in docker?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, should be the same no matter where it runs.